# Extracting values from clob in oracle db separated by a delimiter

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an Oracle DB CLOB field which stores xml in it. I need to retrieve all values in all the  xml with DistributionNbr tag I have used the below query for the same and providing a sample xml for ref.

```
select extract(xmltype(column_name),'//*/xmlpath/text()').getStringval() as g 
from table;
```

```
<xml>
<ShipConfirm>
<ShipmentID>000000196</ShipmentID>
</ShipConfirm>
<ShipConfirm>
<ShipmentID>000000197</ShipmentID>
</ShipConfirm>
<ShipConfirm>
<ShipmentID>000000198</ShipmentID>
</ShipConfirm>
</xml>
```

Now I am getting values as a single string: `000000196000000197000000198`

I need to get a comma separated value or value in next line. `000000196,000000197,000000198`

OR

```
000000196
000000197 
000000198
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid unnecessary '//' operators... and the column patterns are implicitly relative to the row pattern

```
SQL> with MY_TABLE as
  2  (
  3    select 1 as PRIMARY_KEY,
  4           XMLTYPE(
  5  '<xml>
  6    <ShipConfirm>
  7     <ShipmentID>000000196</ShipmentID>
  8    </ShipConfirm>
  9    <ShipConfirm>
 10      <ShipmentID>000000197</ShipmentID>
 11    </ShipConfirm>
 12    <ShipConfirm>
 13      <ShipmentID>000000198</ShipmentID>
 14     </ShipConfirm>
 15  </xml>') as XML_DOC
 16      from DUAL
 17  )
 18  SELECT LISTAGG( x.ShipmentID, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY idx )  AS ShipmentIDs
 19    FROM MY_TABLE t,
 20         XMLTABLE(
 21           '/xml/ShipConfirm'
 22            PASSING XML_DOC
 23            COLUMNS
 24              idx FOR ORDINALITY,
 25              ShipmentID CHAR(9) PATH 'ShipmentID'
 26         ) x
 27  GROUP BY t.primary_key
 28  /

SHIPMENTIDS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
000000196,000000197,000000198

SQL>
SQL>
```

Comment: See the LIVESQL Here https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E7E0NODMZ5BTXA3BXNF2XFB14.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `XMLTABLE`:

```
SELECT x.ShipmentID
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '//xml/ShipConfirm'
          PASSING XMLTYPE( t.column_name )
          COLUMNS ShipmentID CHAR(9) PATH './ShipmentID'
       ) x;
```

That will return it in rows.

If you want it as comma-delimited values then you can use:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( x.ShipmentID, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY idx )
         AS ShipmentIDs
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '//xml/ShipConfirm'
          PASSING XMLTYPE( t.column_name )
          COLUMNS ShipmentID CHAR(9) PATH './ShipmentID',
                  idx FOR ORDINALITY
       ) x
GROUP BY t.primary_key;
```

Comment: In oracle the CROSS JOIN is not required. There is an implicit lateral join between the rows generated by the table function (XMLTABLE) and the row that provided the input to the table function.

Comment: @markddrake You need either a comma (which, without a filter in the `WHERE` clause, will be the equivalent of a `CROSS JOIN` in the legacy Oracle join syntax) or a `CROSS JOIN` in the ANSI join syntax. I just use `CROSS JOIN` as the ANSI syntax rather than reverting back to the legacy syntax.